# MongoDB Covered Queries

Tags: mongodb

I am not sure if I've understood completely covered queries concept. We have a covered query if it can be answered using only the information stored in the index. Using projections is usual in order to have covered queries.

If our query does 'sort' in addition to 'find', the 'sort' part needs to be covered by the index in order to have a Covered Query ?

I think so, but as I haven't found an explicit answer on the internet, I prefer asking.

Thank you, Ane

Comment: welcome to SO,well that's more useful if you put your code that tried in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find an explicit answer too, but it's logical - if you need to sort, you need to have the data according to which you are sorting. And if this data is not stored in the index, you need to read them from somewhere else, and then you don't have a covered query, because the point if a covered query is that you don't have to look anywhere other than the index.

You can check this using [explain()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/explain-results/).

Comment: Well explained. Would also like to point out that if you run an explain() on a covered query, the `indexOnly` field will be true.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much, your answers were very helpful.
I've done some tests in a local collection, and indeed sorting part needs to be covered by the index in order to have a covered query.

Example : 
1 .- I've created an index in an empty collection :

```
db.myCollection.createIndex({x:1,y:1,z:1})
```

2 .- I've inserted data

```
db.myCollection.insert({x:5})
```

3.- I've done different queries and used 'explain' in order to see if the query is covered (indexOnly:true)

```
db.myCollection.find({x:5},{x:1,_id:0}) --> it is covered !
db.myCollection.find({x:5},{x:1,_id:0}).sort({x:1}) --> it is covered !
db.myCollection.find({x:5,y:4},{x:1,_id:0}).sort({x:-1,y:-1}) --> it is covered!


db.myCollection.find({x:5},{x:1,_id:0}).sort({z:1}) --> it is NOT covered !
db.myCollection.find({x:5},{x:1,_id:0}).sort({y:-1,x:-1}) --> it is NOT covered !
```

So this example shows that 'sort' influences in the fact that a query being a Covered Query

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/#covered-queries) say `indexOnly` field is not available in latest versions of MongoDB. Instead, we have to check that we have an IXSCAN stage that is not a descendant of a FETCH stage and totalDocsExamined is 0.